# Any point in the convex hull of the graph of a concave function can be represented as a convex combination of two points

Tags: convex-geometry, convex-hulls

Let us take a continuous concave function $f:[0,1]^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}_+$. The convex hull of its graph is given by, $co(G(f))=\{(x,y)\in[0,1]^n \times \mathbb{R}_+:x=\sum\limits^n_{i=1}\alpha_ix_i,y=\sum\limits^n_{i=1}\alpha_if(x_i),\alpha_i \geq 0, \sum\limits^n_{i=1}\alpha_i=1.\}$ My question is, can any point $(x,y) \in co(G(f))$ be represented as $(x,y)=\alpha(x_1,f(x_1))+(1-\alpha)(x_2,f(x_2))$? I'm aware of the Caratheodory theorem which says we need at most $n$ points for the convex combination, which is why I used $n$ in the definition. The question is whether this can be done by exactly two.

Comment: $(0.5,0)=0.5 \times (0,0)+0.5 \times (1,0)$, so it can in fact be expressed as a convex combination of exactly two points on the graph of $f(x)$. The question was, can every point in $conv(G_f)$ be expressed as a convex comb of *exactly* two  points from $G_f$.

Comment: But how would that show that it cannot be expressed as a convex combination of two points? Those two points need not be extreme points of the domain. For your example, take the regular pyramid with base=[0,1]^2, attains max at (0.5,0.5). The convex hull is the solid pyramid, and it seems if you take any point in it and draw a line "parallel" to the base, you do cut the boundary of the pyramid at two points (actually it doesn't even necessarily have to be parallel.)

Comment: Also, Caratheodory for connected set requires only n points. http://users.mat.unimi.it/users/libor/AnConvessa/Caratheodory_bis_talk.pdf

Comment: Ah I see  your point. Sure $G_f$ is a $n+1$ dimensional object so you're right. In general it won't require *more than* $n+1$ points by Caratheodory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the counterexample:
$$
f(x,y) = x(1-x) + y(1-y).
$$
Then $f(x,y)\ge0$ for all $(x,y)\in [0,1]^2$, and $f$ is zero exactly at the four corners of $[0,1]^2$.

Then $[0,1]^2 \times \{0\} \subset conv(G_f)$, but $(0.5, 0.25, 0)$ is not a convex combination of two points of $G_f$.

Comment: Thanks so much. This makes the intuition very clear why it won't hold.